# How to repeat a image from IMAGE formula for N times by rows in google sheets

Tags: image, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, qr-code, repeat

I want to repeat a qr code generated from web by for n times
[image]

when I enter 3 in C2 i need to get 3 barcodes in D2:D4 as shown in the above image

[sheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AbQtorIU-zmz1BtwcyXVuXSQd_B0BBIvALxHfCB2vHY/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Make sure to also add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE/LINK) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables makes **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets/images as the only source of data, your question may be closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IMAGE(QUERY(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REPT(
 "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl="&
 ENCODEURL(A2)&"​", C2), "​")), "where Col1 is not null", )))
```

[image]